# How can I install my own fonts from several subfolders?

Tags: installation, xubuntu, fonts, xfce

(System: Xubuntu 12.10 with XFCE)

Hello,

I have a folder named *Fonts* on my windows partition which is mounted automatically on boot (why, I don't know, but I like it!). The fonts are sorted in subfolders based on their style (sans, serif, monospace or handwritten). These subfolder contains several .zip-files and their unzipped folders. So in total, these subfolders contain lots of .ttf and .otf files.

Can I somehow copy all those .ttf and .otf files to their respective folders truetype, type1 etc. in /usr/share/fonts with a somewhat simple action? Going through all the font-folders would be mind-numbing. :/

**edit** I can answer my own question:

```
sudo find . -name "*.ttf" -exec cp "{}" /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ ";"
```

and

```
sudo find . -name "*.otf" -exec cp "{}" /usr/share/fonts/type1/ ";"
```

is what helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From OP:

> I can answer my own question:
>
> ```
> sudo find . -name "*.ttf" -exec cp "{}" /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ ";"
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> sudo find . -name "*.otf" -exec cp "{}" /usr/share/fonts/type1/ ";"
> ```
>
> is what helped me.